# Почему read(buffer, length) отображает некорректные символы вместо текста из файла?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    string file_name = "D:\123.txt";
    string key = "bacon";

    ifstream fin;//читатть
    fin.open(file_name, std::ifstream::binary);

    //int   lenght = length(fin);
    fin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
    std::streamsize length = fin.gcount();
    fin.clear();   //  Since ignore will have set eof.
    fin.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    


    char * buffer = new char[length];
        fin.read(buffer, length);

/////////////////////////////////
        cout << buffer[0];//here
 ////////////////////////////////  

    /*auto temp = encrypt(buffer, key);

    fin.close();

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("D:\S.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc | ios_base::binary);


    char* str = new char[temp.size() + 1];
    strcpy(str, temp.c_str());
    fout.write(str, length);*/
return 0;
}
```

Comment: В какой кодировке файл? Судя по названию файла у вас windows, а там консоль в кодировке cp866. А файл может быть либо в UTF-8, либо в виндовой кодировке Win-1251.

Comment: И что, `"D:\123.txt"` работает? Не `"D:\\123.txt"`? У вас точно файл открывается?

Comment: Добавьте хоть одну проверку, что файл открыт и что все функции выполняются корректно, а не просто игнорируются из-за того, что `fin.good() == false`...

Comment: вы оказались правы! необходимы были \\ а файл действительно стоило проверить , открылся ли. Теперь всегда буду проводить такую проверку. Ранее думал что это лишнее

Answer (score 1):

нужно исправить эту часть

```
fin.open(file_name, std::ifstream::binary);
```

на это

```
fin.open(file_name);
```

либо на это

```
fin.open(file_name, std::ifstream::in);
```

Comment: Да мне надо бы с бинарными файлами работать

Answer (score 0):

В данном коде я допустил 3 ошибки:
Первая заключалась в отсутствии проверки открылся ли файл
Вторая в недостатке \ в строке
И третья, при поиске размера файла, мною не был закрыт объект ifstream и последующий код начинал свою работу не с начала файла, а с конца, что естественно приводило к ошибкам